# Vue 3.2 / Watcher for Prop not working in SFC + Script Setup

Tags: vuejs3, vue3-sfc-loader

My setup is as follows:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  count: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
})

const { count } = toRefs(props)

watch(count, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  console.log(newValue, oldValue);
})
</script>
```

The console log is never run.

If I on the other hand set `{ immediate: true }`, it does run but only logs out the new value - old is always undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need `toRefs` in this instance? You can directly watch the prop.

Comment: @Thomas Using `watch(props.count, () => {})` doesn't work.
"Argument type InferPropType<{default: number, type: NumberConstructor}> is not assignable to parameter type [...MultiWatchSources] "

Comment: How about `watch(() => props.count, (count, prevCount) => {})` as also described here to be used for getters: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watching-a-single-source

Comment: By chance did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to add watchers on props in Composition API with script setup.

The solution proposed by Thomas in the question's comments solve the issue.

```
//Not working     
watch(props.count, () => {console.log('hello')})
//Working
watch(() => props.count, () => {console.log('hello')})
```